# Vite preprocessor generate css from my png image

Tags: reactjs, vite

Why vite preprocessor generate css file from my png image in my React app?

```
import imgProducts from '../../images/products.png';

<img
  src={imgProducts}
/>
```

And "yarn build" generated 2 css files. One main and second with this png image. file is index2.css and when I rename it to .png I can open it as my original image.

How to tell vite preprocessor to stop dooing that?